# AutoCompleteTextView widget

Tags: android

I have an alphabetically sorted list of strings for the AutoCompleteTextView,
some strings have 2 words,
when I type a letter, I would that the autocomplete list that appear shows the strings sorted by the letter typed

for example:
I have this list alphabetically sorted: New Orleans, Omaha, Portland, Rome

now, if I type 'O', the first string in the autocomplete list, is New Orleans, the second Omaha,
but I would that Omaha is the first string because it start with 'O' and after New Orleans that doesn't

Answer (score 0):

[multiAutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html) can be looked into to handle sub strings!